# GRPC Generate Sources - Java IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grpc

I'm following this [tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/basics/) for GRPC, my problem is that when I run "mvn protobuf:compile" the files are getting generated in the target folder, I'm not sure how to generate the code to the java dir, here is my POM file

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java-util -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc-2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.33.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.33.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>1.33.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- necessary for Java 9+ -->
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>annotations-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.53</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.12.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.33.1:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And here is my [proto](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/proto/route_guide.proto) file,

Here are my questions,

```
1- The sources are generated in the target folder, I can import them just fine but why in Google docs it shows in the main/java/io..etc folder?
2- stubs like RouteGuideBlockingStub are not getting generated with mvn protobuf:compile, should I be using something else?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generated sources are not really that useful unless you want to distribute your code as a library with source code available. Generated classes are more than enough to work with GRPC. And project builds faster.

`protobuf-maven-plugin` can be configured to use path of your choice for generated classes via `outputDirectory` in plugin configuration section.

Just don't put them into your sources folder.

`protobuf:compile` will get you only protobuf definitions.
To get grpc stubs you need `compile-custom` goal as configured in the build.

Usually there's no need to invoke them separately, just compile the whole project and you're fine.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in the other answer about the directory structure restrictions for proto files, here is how you should configure the pom.xml file to compile and locate your generated classes into your java class files.

following dependencies are required in order to compile and generate necessary class files.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
        <version>1.33.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
        <version>1.33.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
        <version>1.33.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

You also need following 2 plugins:

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugins>
    ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.11.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.27.2:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```